# Parsing DICOM tags to an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I am using dcm4chee2 to parse through tags with their `DicomInputStream` and `DicomObject`. I am then converting the metadata into a ArrayList of type String. However, when I use the toString() method to convert the tags from DicomObject to a String, I am noticing I am not getting a full list of DICOM tags, VR Codes, and Description. Can anyone tell me if there is another DicomObject method I should be using to get a full list rather than the toString()?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
    ArrayList<String> dicomTags = new ArrayList<String>();
    DicomInputStream din = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("dicomTagResults.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    din = new DicomInputStream(new File(pathName));
    try {
        DicomObject dcmObj = din.readDicomObject();
        dicomTags.add(dcmObj.toString());
        for (String findMatch : dicomTags){
            System.out.println(findMatch.toString());
            oos.writeObject(dicomTags);
            oos.close();
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
toStringBuffer(StringBuffer sb, DicomObjectToStringParam param)
```

and define a different DicomObjectToStringParam object (I suspect that it is not providing all of the attributes because the defaults are too small for your dataset).

If you truly want to loop through all of the attributes, you're probably better off using

```
Iterator<DicomElement> data = dcmObj.datasetIterator();
```

and handling the sequence elements appropriately as you loop through the iterator.

Comment: Ok awesome I will try that. What would I need to do to create a variable for DicomObjectToStringParam? I tried using this method previously but got stuck on how to apply it to my code.

Comment: Just use the constructor as appropriate for your object public DicomObjectToStringParam(boolean name, int valueLength, int numItems, int lineLength, int numLines, String indent, String lineSeparator)

Comment: Do you know of any examples on how to use that method correctly? I dont have any of those variables that you mentioned in my code so I am suspecting I will have to add thay

Comment: I don't have any that differ from the default that is created in that class. Have a look at that class to see what the defaults are and increase/alter them as needed.